# How do I use subroutine arguments in a format statement in perl5?

Tags: perl, format

I want to be able to do something like:

```
sub prline {
        format STDOUT =
@<<<< @>>>>>> @>>>>>>
@_
.
write;
}

prline("EPIC", "BUY", "SELL");
```

but it doesn't work. What's the fix?

**Update 1:**

I find the format statement still to be completely mystifying. How comes the following outputs a blank line?

```
my ( $epic, $buy, $sell ) = qw( EPIC BUY SELL );
write();

format STDOUT =
@<<<< @>>>>>> @>>>>>>
$epic, $buy, $sell
.
```

Comment: The builtin are ..weird. Have a look at [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form). This is a great module for Perl 5.

Comment: Your format seems to work for me. However, it works because the lexical variables you used are in the same scope as the format definition. But then, your original code works too. There must be something else that's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the format (as you have done), fill in package variables, then use `write` to make it happen. I have something close to what you want in [an article I wrote for The Effective Perler](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/08/use-formats-to-create-paginated-plaintext-reports/). You still have to use package vars, but you can localize them:

```
foreach my $record ( @cats ) {
    local( $id, $name, $food ) = @$record;
    write( $fh );
    }
```

[Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com) used to have a whole chapter on formats during the Perl 4 days, and I've reproduced that in [Formats](https://www.learning-perl.com/2014/07/formats/) on the book's website.

Comment: I added Update 1, as I still don't understand how `format` is supposed to work. There's presumably something fundamental that I'm not understanding.

Comment: The code in Update 1 does not print a blank link as you claim.

Comment: Both of your code examples work for me. I think you are having other problems.